# Parsing a char to u32

Tags: rust

As the questions states, how do I achieve this?

If I have a code like this:

```
let a = "29";
for c in a.chars() {
    println!("{}", c as u32);
}
```

What I obtain is the unicode codepoints for 2 and 9:

- 50
- 57

What I want is to parse those characters into the actual numbers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[`char::to_digit(radix)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_digit) does that. `radix` denotes the "base", i.e. 10 for the decimal system, 16 for hex, etc.:

```
let a = "29";
for c in a.chars() {
    println!("{:?}", c.to_digit(10));
}
```

It returns an `Option`, so you need to `unwrap()` it, or better: `expect("that's no number!")`. You can read more about proper error handling in [the appropriate chapter of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html).

Comment: Thank you, I feel like the dumbest user in SO. I think one of the main problems I'm having in learning Rust, is navigating the documentation. If you google "Rust Char", you get the documentation for the module: [link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/char/) which does not include the method you mention. I see now that it is because it's part of the type and not the module, it just didn't seem obvious froms the docs to "look there". </rant>

Thanks again!

Comment: in turn, as a rust beginner myself, this was the first rust question I could answer :-) As for docs: I'm using Dash for mac, which is just a wrapper around the docs you linked but somehow I find the things faster there than on the web (e.g. searching for char leads you to the primitive type and not to the module)

Comment: Had not heard of dash before (funny, given my username). You just blew my mind. Thank you, kind stranger.

Comment: @Dash83: Yes, it's an issue with primitive types, with functions some time defined in one place and sometimes in another...

Comment: @hansaplast: Note that you can have the docs as local html pages, which eliminates network round-trips... and nice first answer, short, to the point, and with nice tips for the future!

Comment: @Dash83: don't feel bad, that's what we're here for! I hope the two of you enjoy getting into Rust so far! Feel free to join [the SO Rust chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust) if you want to talk about rusty stuff! :)

Comment: Thanks, @LukasKalbertodt

Comment: this didn't work for me, but `as u8` did

Answer (score 15):

Well, you can always use the following hacky solution:

```
fn main() {
    let a = "29";
    for c in a.chars() {
        println!("{}", c as u32 - 48);
    }
}
```

[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) digits are encoded with values from 48 to 57, so when you have a string containing characters 2 and 9 and attempt to interpret them as integers, you get 50 and 57. To get their expected values you just need to subtract 48 from them.

Comment: The answer by @hansaplast is just what I was looking for. Thanks though.