# Why I am getting an error while unwrapping .to_digit option called on char?

Tags: rust

I am trying to parse a single `char` variable into ASCII value, but all the time I am getting an error.

Basing on answer of **hansaplast** from this post ***[Parsing a char to u32](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41380557/9095988)*** I thought this code should work:

```rust
let char_variable = 'a';
let shoud_be_u32_varaible = a.to_digit(10).unwrap();
```

But this code will always throw this error:

> thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value'

For this, code example (example provided in answer of **hansaplast**):

```rust
let a = "29";
for c in a.chars() {
    println!("{:?}", c.to_digit(10));
}
```

This `.to_digit()` method will work.

In both cases I am using on `.to_digit(10)` on variables which are type of **`char`**, but for my example this code throws an error and for the code from  **hansaplast** this works. Can someone explain to me what is the difference between those examples and what I am doing wrong because now I am super confused?

> Both examples can be found there: **[Rust playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d067df60a545dffd9963d755661406d8)**

---

Is using casting in this case will be ok?

```rust
let c = 'a';
let u = c as u32 - 48;
```

If not, can you tell me, what is recommended of doing this?

Comment: ``'a'`` is not a digit in base 10. What value would you expect from the result?

Comment: What do you mean by "parse a single `char` variable into unicode"? All `char`s are already Unicode code points by definition. If you mean "get the number of this code point" then that's just `c as u32` - no need to subtract 48 or anything else.

Comment: Basing on this [table](https://bournetocode.com/projects/GCSE_Computing_Fundamentals/pages/img/ascii_table_lge.png) I thought I should get 97

Comment: That's the ASCII value. That's also two digits.

Comment: What are you intending to *do* with this value once you’ve obtained it?  Chances are you’re going about solving your problem the wrong way here.

Comment: @eggyal I am planning to multiply it and create a hash

Comment: @tadman Sorry but, I do not understand

Comment: @KrzysztofKaczyński: `char` already implements the `std::hash::Hash` trait.  It sounds like you’re trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: The code in the question you linked (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41380557/9095988) would probably work in your case, but the code in the answer won't.

Comment: OK I think I understood my mistake. I am trying to parse a value which is not a decimal value like `2 1`  provided in the answer of question which I have linked. Thank you all for your help. @trentcl If you would like to move your first and second comment into answer section I would approve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I think you are confusing type casting and integer parsing.

`to_digit` is an integer parsing method. It takes the character and given a radix determines its value in that base. So 5 in base 10 is 5 and is stored as `00000101`. 11 in base 15 is stored in memory as `00010000`.

Type casting of primitives in rust like `'c' as u32` is probably more what you are after. It's distinct from integer parsing in the sense that you don't care about the "meaning" of the number what you care about is the value of the bits that represent it in memory. This means that the character 'c' is stored as `1100011` (99).

If you only care about ascii characters you should also check `char.is_ascii()` before doing your conversion. That way you can store your results in a `u8` instead of a `u32`

```rust
fn print_ascii_values_of_characters(string: &str) {
  for c in string.chars() {
        if c.is_ascii() {
            println!("{:b}", c as u8) // :b prints the binary representation
        }
    }
}
```